# Xaml PropertyChange event not fired when field is empty

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a textbox as a filter that takes a number value

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding CourseNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

By Default this is set to 0 when the page loads. if i click search I bring back what is expected. If I then enter 204 into this textbox i get the appropriate items - only those items with a courseNumber of 204.

Then if I delete anything in here - so its now empty and click search it is still holding onto this 204 value. the property change event is not being fired when I empty this field or when i empty the field and tab off it.

```
    private int _courseNumber;
    public int CourseNumber
    {
        get { return _courseNumber; }
        set
        {
            SetObject(ref _courseNumber, value, "CourseNumber");
            if (_courseNumber!= null)
            {
                OnPropertyChange("CourseNumber")
            }
        }
    }
```

i can get this property change event to fire when inserting other numbers - just not when I removed all data from this field

**Fix for us**
we wound up changing this property to a string instead of an int - then cast it in our search method - this worked perfectly.

Comment: You could also have used a nullable int `int?`.  (Then of course you'd need to remove the null check for raising `OnPropertyChanged`.